# How to use CASE in postgres function to return Select statement?

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

I am trying to write a function with an argument which is supposed to return one of two SELECTs depending on the argument of this fucntion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx(m integer)
RETURNS SETOF AS $$
BEGIN
    CASE m
        WHEN 1 then return query select * from pg_catalog.pg_roles
        WHEN 2 then return query select * from pg_catalog.pg_auth_members
    END
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT fx(1);
```

Sorry I am completely new to sql functions so what am I doing wrong exactly?
I am getting this error while executing:

"SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function fx(integer) does not exist
Hint: No function matchesthe given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts"

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: you get "function fx does not exist" because the function was never created as `returns setof as $$` is invalid to begin with. But you will need to use `returns table()` and specify the columns you want. You can't return a different set of columns depending on the input parameters. Additionally: each statement inside a [CASE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.6.6) also needs to be terminated with a `;` and the CASE needs to be ended with a `END CASE;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi! Thank you for response! But how can I specify columns if I have different tables to return depending on function argument? Can you please  show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you *specify columns if I have different tables to return depending on function argument?* You **cannot**. A function must always have the same return type and the exact return must be declared in the function definition.  
You can sort-of get what you are after by having your function return a refcursor; see [Cursors 43.7.3.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) (or the appropriate section for you Postgres version)  Something like:

```
create or replace function confused_function( What_to_do integer) 
  returns refcursor
 language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
  rec  refcursor; 
begin 
    case when What_to_do  = 1 then 
              open rec for select * from t1; 
             
         when What_to_do  = 2 then
              open rec for select * from t2; 
         
        else 
             raise exception 'Invalid What_to_do parameter value specified (%)', What_to_do
                using Hint = 'Value for Parameter: What_to_do must be 1 or 2'; 
    end case; 

    return rec; 
end;
$$;
```

This however transfers the cursor processing to the calling routine. You would be better off writing 2 functions (one for each SQL). Let the calling routine analyze the 'parameter' and invoke to appropriate function (or just run the SQL without an intervening function).  

A little development philosophy: *A function should do one thing, do it well, and know everything it needs accomplish it.* Your function does not know what to do; it needs to be told.